# How to Properly use HTML2PDF and Yii-PDF in Yii?

Tags: php, pdf, yii, html2pdf

Hello I'm new to yii so currently don't know how to properly use this Html2pdf & yii-pdf extension in yii to get the pdf..

What i actually want.. I have a page called `http://localhost/site/Users/Results`.. which is showing the list of users..So If i click on user one, it will open a new page called `http://localhost/site/Applicant/1` 
& for user two, it will be 
`http://localhost/site/Applicant/2` 
So on these pages there is all the information of users. I want to put a download PDF button on this page, If user clicks on it, He will be able to download all his information in PDF. There can be many users. Everyuser will be able to download all his information in pdf.

I got the [html2pdf](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default) & [yii-PDF](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf/) .. I got this settings by searching on google, but unable to find proper example to use it according to my requirements above.

config/main.php

```
'ePdf' => array(
        'class' => 'ext.yii-pdf.EYiiPdf',
        'params' => array(
            'HTML2PDF' => array(
                'librarySourcePath' => 'application.extensions.html2pdf.*',
                'classFile'         => 'html2pdf.class.php', // For adding to Yii::$classMap
                /*'defaultParams'     => array( // More info: http://wiki.spipu.net/doku.php?id=html2pdf:en:v4:accueil
                    'orientation' => 'P', // landscape or portrait orientation
                    'format'      => 'A4', // format A4, A5, ...
                    'language'    => 'en', // language: fr, en, it ...
                    'unicode'     => true, // TRUE means clustering the input text IS unicode (default = true)
                    'encoding'    => 'UTF-8', // charset encoding; Default is UTF-8
                    'marges'      => array(5, 5, 5, 8), // margins by default, in order (left, top, right, bottom)
                )*/
            )
        ),
    ),
```

Here is my controller.

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function createPDF(){
        $html2pdf = Yii::app()->ePdf->HTML2PDF();
        $html2pdf->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('index', array(), true));
        $html2pdf->Output();
    }
}
```

im totally new to yii, so how to use this extension, I have never used any extension before.. is there any other method to download pdf of each user information. any suggestions or and example of working code.

Answer (score 0):

**config/main.php**

```
'ePdf' => array(
            'class' => 'ext.yii-pdf.EYiiPdf',
            'params' => array(
                'HTML2PDF' => array(
                    'librarySourcePath' => 'application.vendors.html2pdf.*',
                    'classFile' => 'html2pdf.class.php', // For adding to Yii::$classMap
                )
            ),
        ),
```

**Controller**

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function createPDF(){
        $pdffilename = 'test.pdf';
        $html2pdf = Yii::app()->ePdf->HTML2PDF();
        $html2pdf->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('index', array(), true));
        ob_clean();
        $html2pdf->Output($pdffilename,"I"); // OUTPUT_TO_BROWSER
        /* OUTPUT_TO_BROWSER = "I" */
        /* OUTPUT_TO_DOWNLOAD = "D" */
        /* OUTPUT_TO_FILE = "F" */
        /* OUTPUT_TO_STRING = "S" */
    }
}
```